# How can I use hibernate annotation filter in spring boot?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I'd like to use hibernate annotiation filter for my spring boot backend, i'm using repos to get the data from the database and i don't know why i get only the unfiltered elements, i configured the entities with the filter annotation and enabled the filter in the controller. Does anyone know what is missing? Or has anyone some experince with using the @filter in spring boot?

```
@CrossOrigin(value = "http://localhost:**")
@RestController
public class MyController {
    public MyController(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }


public class MyController {
    public MyController(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

    @ModelAttribute("id")
    public String getMandatortId(@RequestAttribute String id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Filter mandator_filter = session.enableFilter("equalId");
        mandator_filter.setParameter("id", id);
        return id;
    }}



@Entity
@Table(name = "openuser", schema = "arego", catalog = "")
@FilterDef(name = "equalId", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "id", type = "string")})
@Filters( {@Filter(name = "equalId", condition id = :id")})
@IdClass(PatientEntityPK.class)
public class OpenuserEntity {}
```

Comment: I guess `doesn't work` means your entities get loaded without being filtered here?

Comment: Yes that's my problem

Comment: So you'd better edit the question to be more specific about the issue. Also I guess Spring Boot and Maven have nothing to do here, it's an Hibernate specific.

Comment: Thanks for your hint!

Comment: In your question: FilterDef name= equalId, but in in @Filter name=equaId (without "l"). Typo?

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was that I used a jpa session (I didn't know that) instead of hibernate. Now I'm using hibernate and everything is fine and it works :)